# Git server shows that files are deleted

Tags: git

When I use command "git ls-files" on my computer it shows all the files that I pushed to the repo, and when I do "git status" it shows my branch is up to date with origin/master. But when I ssh into the git repo server, I can't see any files and if I do "git status", it says, "Changes to be committed: " and shows that all the files are deleted. Why is this happening, and how can I see the files on the server?

Comment: May be you made a Commit without adding files to the stage.

Answer (score 1):

Doing a `git reset --hard` in the server should get all of the files back.
WARNING: This WILL reset any changes made to files on the server since the last commit made on the server.

Comment: Thanks, it retrieved all the files. I always do commit and do "git push origin master". Does this have something to do with the files being deleted?